# Google event tracking not working

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I am using a event tracking on download button. When any user click on the download button then this event must be run but this is not happening. This is my code

```
<input  id="changesubmittxt_<?php echo $theme['Theme']['id']; ?>" type="submit" value="Proceed" class="submitButton" onclick="onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'themes', 'theme', 'free theme',, true]);"" />
```

So tell me where i am wrong, Where i pass all parameters correct or i am missing something here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is a typo but you have onClick within the onClick. So first fix that.

In addition, check the reference for the trackEvent method
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiEventTracking

Specifically it says:

> You can use any of the following optional parameters: opt_label, opt_value or opt_noninteraction. If you want to provide a value only for the second or 3rd optional parameter, you need to pass in undefined for the preceding optional parameter.

so you should try

```
<input  id="changesubmittxt_<?php echo $theme['Theme']['id']; ?>" type="submit" value="Proceed" class="submitButton" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'themes', 'theme', 'free theme', undefined, true]);" />
```